# Postgres plpgsql - Using a variable inside of a dynamic create statement

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql, dynamic-sql

Using Postgres pl/pgsql, I'm attempting to create a table using a dynamic EXECUTE command, such as:

```
 ...
 DECLARE
    tblVar varchar := "myTable";
 BEGIN
 EXECUTE 'CREATE TABLE $1 ( 
             foo integer NOT NULL, 
             bar varchar NOT NULL)'
 USING _tblVar;
 ...
```

However, I continue to receive the error message

> ERROR:  syntax error at or near "$1"

If I don't use the `$1` token and, instead, write the string `myTable` it works just fine.

Is there a limitation on using dynamic statements for CREATE calls?

Comment: I think I've figured it out:

    EXECUTE 'CREATE TABLE ' || _tblVar || ' ( 
             foo integer NOT NULL, 
             bar varchar NOT NULL)';

Comment: Thats right - `execute ... using` can only use substitutions where you could normally have bind variables - ie not for table names etc

Comment: Use quote_ident() to avoid SQL injection and other problems with dynamic object names. You might need lower() as well, to create only lower case objects.

Comment: @Frank only if the table name is coming from an untrusted source, and then IMO he should do more than `quote_ident` - such as restrict to `~'^[a-z]{3,10}$'` and add a prefix

Comment: @Jack: It's a variable so you have to protect your database against major problems. The example already shows issues with casing, myTable is going to be mytable in lower case. quote_ident works fine, no restrictions needed. A maximum length might be handy, 63 characters is the max.

Comment: @Frank I'd be worried about postgres bugs being exploited with special/unicode characters, buffer overflows etc, wouldn't you?

Comment: I'm more worried about the dynamic creation of tables to begin with: You need extra permissions for this. And permissions should be as limited as possible. quote_ident() works fine and it's safe, that's why this function exists in the first place.

Comment: 63 utf-8 otctets  is the name length limit, not 63 characters. (in postgresql characters are unicode code points), the type "name" already has the apropriate constraint.

Comment: @FrankHeikens  there is no indication of sql injection in the example code '$1' is for the the `USING` clause, it's not a reference to function arguments.

Answer (score 13):

In addition to what @filiprem wrote, this is how you do it properly:

```
...
DECLARE
   tbl_var text := 'myTable';   -- I would not use mixed case names ..
BEGIN
   EXECUTE '
   CREATE TABLE ' || quote_ident(tbl_var) || '( 
     foo integer NOT NULL, 
   , bar text NOT NULL)';
...
```

Use [`quote_ident()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-QUOTE-LITERAL-EXAMPLE) (or [`format()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-OTHER)) to defend against SQL injection and syntax errors. It double-quotes identifiers with non-standard characters or reserved words.

I also replaced the double-quotes you had around the string value in your example with [single-quotes](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-CONSTANTS).

See:

- [SQL injection in Postgres functions vs prepared queries](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/49699/sql-injection-in-postgres-functions-vs-prepared-queries/49718#49718)
- [Insert text with single quotes in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12320729/939860)

Answer (score 8):

Yes, there is such limitation.

```
EXECUTE 'SELECT aColumn FROM $1' USING tableVar;
```

will *not* work.
You cannot use parameters for table/column names - that's because PostgerSQL query parser must identify all used tables in order to compile the query.

Quote from [PL/pgSQL docs about dynamic SQL commands](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-EXECUTING-DYN):

> Note that parameter symbols can only be used for data values — if you
> want to use dynamically determined table or column names, you must
> insert them into the command string textually. For example, if the
> preceding query needed to be done against a dynamically selected
> table, you could do this:
>
> ```
> EXECUTE 'SELECT count(*) FROM '
>     || tabname::regclass
>     || ' WHERE inserted_by = $1 AND inserted <= $2'
>    INTO c
>    USING checked_user, checked_date;
> ```

As noted in comments below, the cast method is not always feasible, especially for CREATE statements. Better use the [`format(formatstr, *formatarg)`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-FORMAT) function:

```
EXECUTE format(
  'CREATE TABLE %I (%I %I, %I %I)',
  v_tabname,
  v_col1name, v_col1type,
  v_col2name, v_col2type);
```

Side note: this limitation comes from SQL language itself. Parser needs to know table/column names to resolve if query text is correct or not.
Hence it applies to dynamic SQL in other DBMS-es, Oracle for example: http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/dynamic.htm#CHDHGHIF

Comment: For a `CREATE` statement you cannot use the cast `tabname::regclass` in the example because, obviously, the table does not exist, yet.

Answer (score -1):

In the code above, you are using $1 which is an argument which you got as a parameter from the function. In this case, you can't use $1 inside the string. So, the code should be like this

```
EXECUTE 'CREATE TABLE ' || $1 || ' ( 
         foo integer NOT NULL, 
         bar varchar NOT NULL)'
```

In here || this mark indicates that joining a string like + sign

Comment: Sorry, no, $1 is not a parameter in PL/pgSQL.

Comment: then, may I know what is that