# SQL injection in Postgres functions vs prepared queries

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql, prepared-statement, sql-injection, functions

In Postgres, are prepared queries and user defined functions equivalent as a **mechanism for guarding against SQL injection**?
Are there particular advantages in one approach over the other?

Answer (score 58, accepted):

It depends.

#### Prepared statements

A.k.a. "prepared queries". These only take *values* when executed with  [`EXECUTE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-execute.html). No SQL-injection possible at this stage. But you have to defend against SQL-injection while generating / concatenating the statement to be fed to [`PREPARE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-prepare.html) in the first place. Prepared statements are very much equivalent to stored SQL functions / procedures in this regard.

#### SQL functions / procedures

With [`LANGUAGE sql`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/xfunc-sql.html) they are **generally safe**.

Passed parameters are treated as *values* and SQL-injection is not possible - as long as you **don't call unsafe functions from the body** and pass parameters.

#### PL/pgSQL functions /procedures

With [`LANGUAGE plpgsql`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql.html) they are ***normally* safe**.

**However**, PL/pgSQL allows for **dynamic SQL** where passed parameters (or parts) are concatenated to a query string and executed with [**`EXECUTE`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-EXECUTING-DYN). This can convert user input to SQL code and make SQL injection possible. Tools are there to do it safely. You cannot tell from outside whether the function body handles it properly, you have to look at the code.

Plain SQL statements using parameters as values are safe against SQL injection, just like SQL functions. Only use dynamic SQL where needed and follow these guidelines:

Preferably pass ***values*** as values to `EXECUTE` with the **`USING`** clause. Makes SQL injection impossible on principal. [Example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8146245/939860).

**Never** just build strings from user input and execute. This includes identifiers, directly passed by a user or fetched from a system catalog.

- When concatenating ***values*** in the SQL string, wrap 'strings' in **single-quotes** safely. Use:

  - [`format()` with format specifier `%L`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-OTHER). [Example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25156130/939860).
  - [`quote_literal()` or `quote_nullable()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-OTHER). [Example](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/127057/3684).
- When concatenating ***identifiers*** in the SQL string, wrap them in **double-quotes** safely where required. Use:

  - [`format()` with format specifier `%I`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-OTHER). [Example](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/42930/3684).
  - [`quote_ident()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-OTHER). [Example](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/10864/3684).
  - a [cast to a registered type](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-oid.html) - `regclass` for table names:  `_tbl::regclass`. (Only works for *existing* objects!) [Example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10711349/939860).
- Concatenating other parts of the SQL ***code*** is **never safe**, when allowing unchecked user input in any way.

Related:

- [Refactor a PL/pgSQL function to return the output of various SELECT queries](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11751557/939860)
- [Define table and column names as arguments in a plpgsql function?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18386034/939860)

More about **performance implications** in this related answer:

- [Function Performance](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/8119/postgresql-stored-procedure-performance/8189#8189)

Basics on SQL-injection:

- http://bobby-tables.com/

Similar considerations apply to **other server-side languages** that allow dynamic SQL.

Comment: So, in summary: If 1) I use only language sql, I'm safe, 2) if I use plpgslq but not execute, I'm safe, 3) if I use plpgsql and execute but no identifiers and %s or %L as appropriate I'm safe, or 4) if I use plpgsql and execute and identifiers but %I or quote_ident as appropriate I'm safe. Correct?

Comment: @mickeyf: Basically yes. Plus, use the `USING` clause for passing values to `EXECUTE` whenever possible. You *could* call a PL/pgSQL function from within an SQL function and pass parameters. So, to be absolutely correct, you are safe as long as you don't call any unsafe functions directly or indirectly. If all your functions are done properly, that cannot happen.

Comment: Would "Concatenating other parts of the SQL code" be safe if done in `FORMAT` with `%s`?

Comment: @Rafs Generally no. There are exceptions, where SQLi is not possible a priori.