# Dynamically creating a new table from a given table name without return type using a PostgreSQL function?

Tags: postgresql, stored-procedures, plpgsql, postgresql-12

I want to try using PostgreSQL to create a function which given a table name, an existing column name, and a new column name, it selects all data from this table, applies a function to this column name, and adds this new column. The caveat is that I can't specify a "fixed" return type in the sense that the structure of the table will always be different. Although if it helps, I am managing some metadata about these tables which I can probably supply.

Anyway, keeping my example simple, here it is in PLPGSQL:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION add_new_col(from_tbl anyelement,some_col anyelement, new_col_name anyelement)
  RETURNS SETOF anyelement AS $$
BEGIN
  RETURN QUERY EXECUTE 'SELECT *,transformation_func('||some_col||') AS '|| new_col_name || ' FROM '||from_tbl;
END
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Yeah this is basically a wrapper to a select statement, but I am just using it to highlight my point. If it is really needed to specify the schema of the table which the function will return, can I do this within the function itself? I am not in a position to create a function for each different table structure.

I understand that it is very important for the query to know the table structure in advance. Is there a way to specify it outside the function call? Again, my point is not to create many functions for each table structure.

Is what I am trying to achieve impossible through a function? I get the error `ERROR: could not determine polymorphic type because input has type unknown`.

If it helps, I am not limited to PLPGSQL and can even use C. But I really need to specify a function/procedure.

EDIT: I found this [Are there other ways to select a dynamic list of columns?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/53044/are-there-other-ways-to-select-a-dynamic-list-of-columns) to be quite similar to my requirements, I am however quite curious if something changed within these 7 years! I hope to call such a function from a CTE, and I also hope to actually be able to CREATE TABLE the result. I wonder how I can achieve that?

In fact if I could do something with CTAS syntax like CREATE TABLE AS select add_new_col(...) would be very helpful.

Comment: Side-note: Your query `'SELECT *,AVG('||some_col||') AS '|| new_col_name || ' FROM '||from_tbl` is not valid SQL

Comment: ah my bad, i meant a reference to any generic function.

Comment: I don't at all understand your scenario, but you can declare void as return type for your function.

Comment: I would like to be able to use CTAS syntax on the function. I don't think that would work then?

Comment: I assume this is some kind of migration, and I suggest that you do that from your favorite host language that can access the database. The above is really stretching the limit for the purpose of a function

Comment: Yeah! My scenario is quite similar. Furthermore, I was interested in this kind of problem as a theoretical question too.