# Select a dynamic list of columns in Postgres

Tags: postgresql, dynamic-sql

Just wanted to come back to this question as proposed solution (using a temp table)
[Are there other ways to select a dynamic list of columns?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/53044/are-there-other-ways-to-select-a-dynamic-list-of-columns)
didn't exactly work for me.

My scenario (using example from the link above):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION webview.test2(colList VARCHAR)
 RETURNS SETOF record AS
$func$
BEGIN

RETURN QUERY EXECUTE
'SELECT ' || colList || ' FROM webview.webview_account ';

END
$func$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

-- this call works fine but I'd like to avoid explicitly providing the data types in the result
set.

```
SELECT * 
FROM webview.test2('account_number, customer_name') 
AS f(account_number varchar, customer_name varchar);
```

Comment: No, that's not possible.