# Removing all columns with given name

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3, plpgsql, dynamic-sql

I am converting a MSSQL schema to PostgreSQL and in that schema most tables have a column called `Timestamp` that are of MSSQL `timestamp` datatype which is effectively `rowversion`.

When inserting records into those tables you do not need to specify values for timestamp columns as MSSQL auto updates that column.  I believe this is the same as `xmin` in PG.

So now when my app tries to insert into the table PG blows up saying it needs a value for the `Timestamp` column.

I'm therefore thinking after importing the schema writing something that drops all columns from my tables that are called `Timestamp` and have `timestamp` datatype.

I have found I can get column and table info from `pgclass` and `pgattribute` however I"m now stuck how to loop and do checks and then drop columns. Could someone point me in the right direction please?

```
select
    t.relname,
    a.attname,
    d.typname
from
  pg_class t
  INNER JOIN pg_attribute a 
  on a.attrelid = t.oid
  INNER JOIN pg_type d
  on d.oid = a.atttypid
  where relkind='r' and attname = 'timestamp' and d.typname = 'timestamp'
ORDER BY t.relname
```

Answer (score 3):

For a one-time use, you don't need to persist a function. Use a [**`DO`**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-do.html) statement:

```
DO
$do$
DECLARE
   rec record;
BEGIN
FOR rec IN
   SELECT a.attrelid::regclass::text AS tbl, a.attname
   FROM   pg_class c
   JOIN   pg_attribute a ON a.attrelid = c.oid
   WHERE  c.relkind = 'r'
   AND    a.attname = 'timestamp'
   AND    a.atttypid = 'timestamp'::regtype
   AND    a.attnum > 0
   AND    NOT a.attisdropped
LOOP
   RAISE NOTICE '%', format('ALTER TABLE %s DROP COLUMN %I', rec.tbl, rec.attname);
   -- Check test output before uncommenting EXECUTE!
   -- EXECUTE format('ALTER TABLE %s DROP COLUMN %I', rec.tbl, rec.attname);
END LOOP;
END
$do$;
```

#### Major points

- As mentioned at the top, probably no need for a function. The body of a **`DO` statement** is identical, default language is plpgsql.
- Use the implicit cursor of a **`FOR` loop**. Simpler and faster. Explicit cursors are rarely necessary in plpgsql.
- Table names are **not unique** in a Postgres database. There can be any number of tables with the same name in multiple *schemas*.
- Avoid SQL injection and basic exceptions with **non-standard (double quoted) identifiers**.

  - A cast to `regclass` takes care of the table name. At the same time, table names are schema-qualified automatically where necessary (taking the current [`search_path`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9067335/how-to-create-table-inside-specific-schema-by-default-in-postgres/9067777#9067777) into account).
  - `format()` with `%I` sanitizes the column names.

  Details:

  - [SQL injection in Postgres functions vs prepared queries](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/49699/postgres-functions-vs-prepared-queries/49718#49718)
- I assume you are aware of [`timestamp` and `timstamptz` data types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9571392/ignoring-timezones-altogether-in-rails-and-postgresql/9576170#9576170)? This only removes columns with data type `timestamp [without time zone]`.
- Identify the data type with `a.atttypid = 'timestamp'::regtype`, so you don't have to join to `pg_type`. Simpler.
- Exclude system columns and dead columns:
  `AND    a.attnum > 0
  AND    NOT a.attisdroppedand`

Comment: I'm completely new to PostgreSQL, 2 days in so far and learning as I go. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

Well I seem to have got it working like this:

```
DROP FUNCTION somefuncname();
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION somefuncname() RETURNS void LANGUAGE plpgsql AS $$
DECLARE
  tablename VARCHAR(500);
  columnname varchar(500);

  curs1 CURSOR FOR  select
    t.relname,
    a.attname,
    d.typname
    from
    pg_class t
    INNER JOIN pg_attribute a 
    on a.attrelid = t.oid
    INNER JOIN pg_type d
    on d.oid = a.atttypid
    where relkind='r' and attname = 'timestamp' and d.typname = 'timestamp'
    ORDER BY t.relname;

BEGIN
  FOR myrecordvar IN curs1 LOOP 
    RAISE NOTICE E'Table Name:%',myrecordvar.relname;
    EXECUTE 'ALTER TABLE "' || myrecordvar.relname || '" DROP COLUMN ' || myrecordvar.attname;
  END LOOP;
END
$$;
SELECT somefuncname();
```