# Delete rows while updating references

Tags: postgresql, update, delete, dynamic-sql, referential-integrity

Suppose I have a `person` table with an id and some other columns. Other tables reference the `person` table using `ON UPDATE CASCADE`. for instance:

```
CREATE TABLE person (id int PRIMARY KEY);
CREATE TABLE sale (id int PRIMARY KEY,
    person_id int REFERENCES person(id) ON UPDATE CASCADE);
```

Now, what I am trying to do is: **Remove duplicate entries from the person table, fixing the references `sale` references**. For instance, using this data:

```
INSERT INTO person values (1), (2), (3);
INSERT INTO sale VALUES (11, 1), (12, 2), (13, 3);
```

Person `1` and `2` are actually the same, so they should be 'merged'. By merging I mean excluding person `2` while updating the references for person `1` in the `sale` table.

Since there is an `ON UPDATE CASCADE` on the table that references person, I wonder if there is some way to, without having to manually update the `sale` table, cause the cascade update while deleting the person `2`

What I am trying to achieve here is avoiding a dedicated procedure to update the references since the number of referring tables will most likely increase, requiring maintenance in this procedure (and it is quite big already).

Comment: By what criteria is a person with different ids the same?

Comment: The user will define. They may have the exact same name, or similar names (with typos), missing a middle name, etc...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, there is no built-in feature for merging one key into another, updating all referencing rows automatically. There could be all kinds of complications you need to resolve.

#### Simple case

You need to run `UPDATE` on all referencing tables and `DELETE` on the referenced table. The **simple case** would look like this:

```
BEGIN;

--  1. update references
UPDATE sale
SET    person_id = _org_id
WHERE  person_id = _dupe_id;

-- 2. kill dupe 
DELETE FROM person
WHERE  id = _dupe_id;

COMMIT;
```

But there may be all kinds of ...

#### Complications

Imagine a table `person_tag` implementing an n:m relationship between `person` and `tag` with a unique constraint on `(person_id, tag_id)`. You can't `UPDATE` rows that would result in duplicate tags. You need to **resolve conflicts**: only update rows that do not conflict with the unique constraint and delete the rest.

```
-- example for conflict resolution
UPDATE person_tag pt
SET    person_id = _org_id
WHERE  person_id = _dupe_id
AND NOT EXISTS (
   SELECT 1 FROM person_tag
   WHERE  person_id = _org_id
   AND    tag_id = pt.tag_id
   );

DELETE FROM person_tag
WHERE  person_id = _dupe_id;
-- end person_tag
```

There may be more sophisticated constellations ...

### Full automation

If you have lots of referencing tables that can be treated in the same fashion (or a changing number), you can automate the procedure with **dynamic SQL**.

For the **simple case** with a single-column fk constraint and no complications:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_merge_id(_tbl regclass, _col text, _org_id int, _dupe_id int)
  RETURNS void AS
$func$
DECLARE
   rec record;
BEGIN
   FOR rec IN  -- find all referencing columns
      SELECT c.conrelid::regclass AS tbl, quote_ident(a2.attname) AS col
      FROM   pg_catalog.pg_attribute  a1
      JOIN   pg_catalog.pg_constraint c  ON c.confrelid = a1.attrelid
                                        AND c.confkey   = ARRAY[a1.attnum]
      JOIN   pg_catalog.pg_attribute  a2 ON a2.attrelid = c.conrelid
                                        AND a2.attnum   = c.conkey[1]
      WHERE  a1.attrelid = _tbl
      AND    a1.attname  = _col
      AND    c.contype   = 'f'  -- fk constraint
   LOOP        -- Redirect to _org_id all references to dupe_id
      EXECUTE format('
         UPDATE %1$s
         SET    %2$s = $1
         WHERE  %2$s = $2'
        ,rec.tbl, rec.col)
      USING _org_id, _dupe_id;
   END LOOP;

   -- Finally kill (now orphaned) dupe 
   EXECUTE format('DELETE FROM %s WHERE %s = $1', _tbl, _col)
   USING _dupe_id;
END
$func$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Call:

```
SELECT f_merge_id('person', 'person_id', _org_id := 1, _dupe_id := 2);
```

This updates **any number of tables** that have a foreign key referencing the master table.

Using named parameters in the call, which is not required, but you'll want to make sure  **not** to confuse original and duplicate here.

[**SQL Fiddle.**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/cae62/3)

#### Major points

- If you are unfamiliar with the concept of dynamic SQL in plpgsql functions, refer to some of the related questions:

  - https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/postgresql+dynamic-sql+plpgsql
- Quote column names correctly to avoid SQL injection. `quote_ident()` does that for you:

  - [SQL injection in Postgres functions vs prepared queries](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/49699/sql-injection-in-postgres-functions-vs-prepared-queries/49718#49718)
- If you have to deal with heavy concurrent load, you must be prepared that the final `DELETE` can fail, which would roll back the whole transaction. Concurrent transactions could enter new rows with `_dupe_id`. There are various ways to deal with that, which goes beyond the scope of this question.

Comment: I was expecting that the final solution should be instrospecting the schema using the catalog, but I hoped there would be a way to take advantage of the UPDATE CASCADE. I also didn't consider the mapping table problem. Nicely put.

Comment: @romaia: That's not possible, because the referenced filed(s) must be unique, so you cannot update one row with an existing value of another. There might be some trickery with multi-column fk constraints, but nothing as clean and cheap as my function ...