# How to use variable value inside copy function

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql, dynamic-sql, copy

I want to send data to .csv file using `COPY` function in Postgres. But I am using anonymous block so my table name should be value of variable.

```
COPY (SELECT cname.portal from user) To '/tmp/out.csv' With CSV;
```

Where `cname` is my variable inside anonymous block. I try to use `EXECUTE` format but it also didn't work. I tried something like:

```
EXECUTE format ('    COPY (select * from %s.portal,cname ) To '/tmp/out1.csv' With CSV');
```

Comment: Basic questions about syntax are better suited at http://stackoverflow.com. Please post similar questions there.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In plpgsql code (not in plain SQL!):

```
EXECUTE format($$COPY (select * from %I.portal) TO '/tmp/out1.csv' WITH CSV$$, cname);
```

`cname` being the variable holding a (yet unescaped) schema name.

You need to understand:

- [dollar quoting](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12320729/939860)
- the [`format()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-FORMAT) function
- SQL injection and how to defend against it:

  - [SQL injection in Postgres functions vs prepared queries](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/49699/sql-injection-in-postgres-functions-vs-prepared-queries/49718#49718)

If you are processing this with a client where `$` has a special meaning, you need to escape it properly. As a quick fix, you can switch to:

```
EXECUTE format('COPY (select * from %I.portal) TO ''/tmp/out1.csv'' WITH CSV', cname);
```

Comment: for it I am still getting syntax error.                  EXECUTE format(5222COPY (select  * from %I....

Comment: @user3526905: Seems to be an issue with the `$` character, which seems to be lost in translation. I added an alt.

Comment: Erwin I am not getting any error but it is unable to write to csv file.I am not getting any contents even though there are contents in table.