# Copying CSV file to temp table with dynamic number of columns?

Tags: postgresql, csv, dbms, temporary-tables

I am wondering if there is a way to copy a csv file into a temp table where the number of columns is unknown in the csv file. The DB software I'm using is PgAdmin III. I figured out that if I do know the number of columns then I can create a temp table with that amount of columns and then copy the csv file in like so:

```
   CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temp
   (
      col1 VARCHAR(80),
      col2 VARCHAR(80),
       ....
      coln VARCHAR(80)
   );

COPY temp FROM 'C:/Users/postgres/Boost.txt' CSV HEADER DELIMITER E'    '
```

However if I try to just simply copy the csv file to a temp table with no columns in the temp table, Postgresql (version 8.4) complains that I'm working with a table that has less columns than in the csv file. I've been researching and can't seem to find anything in the Postgresql docs about this. Does anyone know if copying a csv file into a temp table with an arbitrary number of columns decided at run time is possible in Postgresql? Once the temp table is loaded with the csv file I plan on doing some comparisons to other tables with the temp table before it is destroyed. Also the first row in the csv file contains headers.

Comment: You'll want to use an ETL tool or script. Take a look at CloverETL, Talend Studio, Pentaho Kettle. There are probably also a bunch of simple "CSV loader" scripts out there for your preferred scripting language.

Answer (score 6):

Basics:

- The 1st row of the CSV file has column names of defined format.
- The `PROGRAM` clause of `COPY` and `GET DIAGNOSTICS` after `COPY` require Postgres **9.3+**.
- [`format()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-FORMAT) requires Postgres **9.1+**
- This works with pure standard Postgres - except for the `head` command that the shell is expected to provide. For Windows versions consider:
- [How to do what head, tail, more, less, sed do in Powershell?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9682024/939860)

#### Full automation

This function copies *any* table structure **completely dynamically**:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_dynamic_copy(_file    text
                                        , _tbl     text = 'tmp1'
                                        , _delim   text = E'\t'
                                        , _nodelim text = chr(127)) -- see below!
  RETURNS text
  LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$func$
DECLARE
   row_ct int;
BEGIN
   -- create staging table for 1st row as  single text column 
   CREATE TEMP TABLE tmp0(cols text) ON COMMIT DROP;

   -- fetch 1st row
   EXECUTE format($$COPY tmp0 FROM PROGRAM 'head -n1 %I' WITH (DELIMITER %L)$$  -- impossible delimiter
                , _file, _nodelim);

   -- create actual temp table with all columns text
   EXECUTE (
      SELECT format('CREATE TEMP TABLE %I(', _tbl)
          || string_agg(quote_ident(col) || ' text', ',')
          || ')'
      FROM  (SELECT cols FROM tmp0 LIMIT 1) t
           , unnest(string_to_array(t.cols, E'\t')) col
      );

   -- Import data
   EXECUTE format($$COPY %I FROM %L WITH (FORMAT csv, HEADER, NULL '\N', DELIMITER %L)$$
                , _tbl, _file, _delim);

   GET DIAGNOSTICS row_ct = ROW_COUNT;
   RETURN format('Created table %I with %s rows.', _tbl, row_ct);
END
$func$;
```

Call variants:

```
SELECT f_dynamic_copy('/path/to/file.csv');
SELECT f_dynamic_copy('/path/to/file2.csv', 'tmp_file2');
SELECT f_dynamic_copy(_file  => '/path/to/file2.csv'
                    , _tbl   => 'tmp_file2');
                    , _delim => E'\t'); -- using assignment operator since pg 9.5
```

Answer:

```
Created table tmp_file2 with 123 rows.
```

Before the main `COPY`, run a preliminary `COPY ... TO tmp0` to fetch the first row with column names, which are expected to be unquoted, case-sensitive strings like `COPY ... TO ... (FORMAT csv, HEADER)` would export them.

The structure of the actual target table is derived from it, all columns with **data type `text`**. The default name of the resulting table is `tmp1` - or provide your own as **2nd function parameter**.

Then `COPY` is executed. The default delimiter is a tab character - or provide your delimiter as **3rd function parameter**.

Use any single-byte character for the non-delimiter `_nodelim` which does not appear in the first line of your CSV file. I am arbitrarily picking the [control character "Delete" (ASCII 127)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delete_character). That character would be swallowed here on SO, so I generate with `chr(127)` instead, which is also valid. Assuming the character won't pop up - or provide your non-delimiter as **4th function parameter**.

The function returns table name and number of imported rows.
Remember, a temporary table dies with the end of the session.

[The manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-copy.html)

> Executing a command with `PROGRAM` might be restricted by the operating
> system's access control mechanisms, such as SELinux.

Related answer on SO:

- [“ERROR: extra data after last expected column” when using PostgreSQL COPY](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16367586/939860)

#### Postgres 8.4

[Postgres 8.4 is too old](https://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/), not back-porting. Some hints:

- `GET DIAGNOSTICS` is an optional feature. You can just leave it away or replace it with a full count on the table
- A primitive (expensive) alternative for the `PROGRAM` clause of `COPY` in pg 9.3 would be to import the complete table instead:

  ```
    EXECUTE format($$COPY tmp0 FROM %L WITH (DELIMITER %L)$$, _file, _delim);
  ```

Or you prepare a second input file, or you can make it work by piping from the shell: `COPY tablename FROM STDIN` is available in pg 8.4.

- `format()` can be replaced with plain string concatenation. Be wary of SQL injection though!
- [SQL injection in Postgres functions vs prepared queries](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/49699/sql-injection-in-postgres-functions-vs-prepared-queries/49718#49718)

Comment: Well I don't have the option of upgrading at this time. So the line of code `COPY tablename FROM STDIN` is what I would use to replace all instances of `EXECUTE format...` or do I need it for just fetching the first row as the column names and the rest of the rows as data?

Comment: @John: Only for the *first*  instance, the point of which is to fetch the first row only. You could even `COPY` the complete table another time, it  just would be twice the cost. The second instance is a plain `COPY` (dynamically using input parameters). I also added info on `format()`. You should urgently consider upgrading to a current version.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter you're a literal god

Answer (score 1):

This program handles creating PostgreSQL tables based on most any CSV or JSON with one line:

https://github.com/lukasmartinelli/pgfutter