# PostgreSQL trigger function that selects from %current% table

Tags: postgresql, trigger, functions, plpgsql, dynamic-sql

I have multiple tables that have the same column names, they only vary in their column values, like:

```
tbl_log_a
tbl_log_b
tbl_log_c
...
```

26 tables from a to z. Each table has a trigger that calls a trigger function which does the exact same thing:

```
SELECT columnname FROM tbl_log_a
```

Other than that, all my trigger functions do the exact same thing. They differ in that they:

```
select columnname FROM tbl_log_a
select columnname FROM tbl_log_b
select columnname FROM tbl_log_c
...
```

So I have to create 26 trigger functions, one for each `tbl_log_%letter%`. Is there a way to tell the trigger function to:

```
SELECT columnname FROM %currenttable%
```

By `%currenttable%` I mean the table where the trigger is placed. Or:

```
SELECT columnname FROM tbl_log_%letter%
```

Is it possible in **Postgres 9.1**? I'm reading about dynamically determined tables. Any clue? I would like to store the table name itself inside a variable, not the columns inside that table, because the trigger function works on multiple columns inside that table.

```
TG_TABLE_NAME
TG_TABLE_SCHEMA
```

Comment: Follow-up to this question: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/112288/trigger-function-using-current-row-and-current-table-name-as-variables

Comment: Other comments on this question [are archived here](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/90145/discussion-on-question-by-natysiu16-postgresql-trigger-function-that-selects-fro).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I suggested that you use trigger arguments, but it's actually not necessary. You can use the [automatic variables](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-trigger.html) `TG_TABLE_SCHEMA` and `TG_TABLE_NAME`, or use `TG_RELID`. These, alongside `EXECUTE` for dynamic SQL, let you do what you want:

```
BEGIN
    EXECUTE format('SELECT colname FROM %I', TG_RELID)
END;
```

or

```
BEGIN
    EXECUTE format('SELECT colname FROM %I.%I', TG_TABLE_SCHEMA, TG_TABLE_NAME)
END;
```

(Of course these won't work as-is, since the `SELECT` has no destination for the data. You have to use `EXECUTE format(..) INTO ...` to store the result into a `DECLARE`d variable), e.g.

```
DECLARE
    _colvar integer;
BEGIN
    EXECUTE format('SELECT colname FROM %I.%I', TG_TABLE_SCHEMA, TG_TABLE_NAME) INTO _colvar;
    RAISE NOTICE 'colname value was %',_colvar;
END;
```

Comment: Comments on this answer have been [archived](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/90144/discussion-on-answer-by-craig-ringer-postgresql-trigger-function-that-selects-fr).

Answer (score 3):

The actual syntax corresponding to the imaginary `SELECT columnname FROM %currenttable%`
would be, in plpgsql:

```
execute format('SELECT columnname FROM %I.%I',
                TG_TABLE_SCHEMA, TG_TABLE_NAME);
```

The TG_* built-in variables are documented in [Trigger Procedures](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-trigger.html)
and the `execute` and `format` plpgsql constructs in [Basic Statements](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-statements.html).

The query above is absurd by itself (it selects results that go nowhere); the intent is to just show the base syntax on which an actual query could be built.

Answer (score 3):

Or you can use **`TG_RELID`**, but since its data type is plain `oid`, not `regclass`, one must cast it to `regclass` explicitly to get the auto-conversion to a schema-qualified (only if the current `search_path` requires it), cleanly escaped table name. [The documentation:](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/plpgsql-trigger.html)

> `TG_RELID`
>
> Data type **`oid`**; the object ID of the table that caused the trigger invocation.

Bold emphasis mine. I wonder why they did not make it `regclass` to begin with ...

```
EXECUTE format('SELECT columnname FROM %s', TG_RELID::regclass);
```

And it's still unclear what you are doing with the result. Typically, you would use that in an `INSERT` / `UPDATE` / `DELETE` statement or [write the result to a variable](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-EXECUTING-DYN):

```
EXECUTE format('SELECT columnname FROM %s', TG_RELID::regclass)
INTO my_variable;
```

Only the first value is assigned. If `SELECT` finds more rows, the rest is discarded. You might want to add `ORDER BY ... LIMIT 1`.

Related:

- [SQL injection in Postgres functions vs prepared queries](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/49699/sql-injection-in-postgres-functions-vs-prepared-queries/49718#49718)
- [How to dynamically use TG_TABLE_NAME in PostgreSQL 8.2?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7617533/939860)
- [Table name as a PostgreSQL function parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10711349/939860)