# Trigger function using current row and current table name as variables

Tags: postgresql, trigger, postgresql-9.1, plpgsql, dynamic-sql

Like [detailed in my first question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/112184/postgresql-trigger-function-that-selects-from-current-table) I have multiple tables with identical layout in a **Postgres 9.1** DB.
They only vary in their column values:

```
tbl_log_a
tbl_log_b
tbl_log_c
...
```

26 tables (from a to z). Each table has a trigger that calls a trigger function named `trfn_tbl_log_%letter%` (from `a` to `z`) which does the exact same thing:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION trfn_tbl_log_a
  RETURNS trigger AS
$BODY$
DECLARE
v_timeidx real;

BEGIN

IF NEW.timetype = 'start' THEN
  SELECT timeidx FROM tbl_log_a
  WHERE fnname = NEW.fnname AND timetype = 'start'
  ORDER BY stmtserial DESC LIMIT 1 INTO v_timeidx;
    IF FOUND THEN
      NEW.timeidx := floor(v_timeidx) + 1;
    ELSE
      NEW.timeidx := 1;
    END IF;

ELSIF NEW.timetype = 'lap' THEN 
  SELECT timeidx FROM tbl_log_a
  WHERE fnname = NEW.fnname AND (timetype = 'start' OR timetype = 'lap')
  ORDER BY stmtserial DESC LIMIT 1 INTO v_timeidx;
    IF FOUND THEN
      NEW.timeidx := v_timeidx + 0.001;
    ELSE
      RAISE EXCEPTION USING MESSAGE = 'There is not any previous row WHERE fnname = NEW.fnname AND (timetype = start OR timetype = lap)';
    END IF;

ELSIF NEW.timetype = 'resume' THEN
  SELECT timeidx FROM tbl_log_a
  WHERE fnname = NEW.fnname AND (timetype = 'start' OR timetype = 'resume')
  ORDER BY stmtserial DESC LIMIT 1 INTO v_timeidx;
    IF FOUND THEN
      NEW.timeidx := v_timeidx + 0.001;
    ELSE
      RAISE EXCEPTION USING MESSAGE = 'There is not any previous row WHERE fnname = NEW.fnname AND timetype = start';
    END IF;

END IF;
return NEW;

END
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Trigger definition:

```
CREATE TRIGGER trfn_tbl_log_a
  BEFORE INSERT ON tbl_log_a
  FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE trfn_tbl_log_a();
```

So I have to create 26 trigger functions, one for each `tbl_log_%letter%`
all of them are exactly the same except for the used table name (`tbl_log_a` in the example).

Is there a way to write *one* generic trigger function, with dynamic SQL maybe and parameterize the table name?

My trigger function uses several table columns:

```
timeidx
fnname
timetype
stmtserial
```

... and many more that I didn't add for size, but all in the example list all the kinds.

Comment: This is a follow-up to: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/112184/postgresql-trigger-function-that-selects-from-current-table and is followed by: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/112324/trigger-function-using-current-row-and-current-table-name-as-variables-final-pa

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that, for the same trigger invocation, you take all the values from the same row in the table firing your trigger, your trigger function could look like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION trfn_tbl_log_any()
  RETURNS trigger AS
$func$
DECLARE
   _ct int;
BEGIN

IF NEW.timetype = 'start' THEN

   EXECUTE format($$
      SELECT floor(t.timeidx) + 1
      FROM   %s t
      WHERE  t.fnname = $1
      AND    t.timetype = 'start'
      ORDER  BY t.stmtserial DESC
      LIMIT  1$$
    , TG_RELID::regclass  -- concatenate *identifer* ..
      )
   USING NEW.fnname        -- .. but pass *value* in USING clause
   INTO  NEW.timeidx;

   GET DIAGNOSTICS _ct = ROW_COUNT;

   IF _ct > 0 THEN  -- do nothing
   ELSE
      NEW.timeidx := 1;
   END IF;
END IF;

RETURN NEW;
END
$func$  LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

All of this should work in Postgres 9.1. But consider upgrading to a current version anyway (currently 9.4).

- `NEW` is not visible inside `EXECUTE`. Use the `USING` clause to pass the value from the new row (`NEW.fnname`).
- Use `TG_RELID` (or `TG_TABLE_SCHEMA` and `TG_TABLE_NAME`) to concatenate the table name like we worked out under your previous question:

  - [PostgreSQL trigger function that selects from %current% table](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/112184/postgresql-trigger-function-that-selects-from-current-table)
- Use [`format()`](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/49718/3684) and [dollar-quoting](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12320729/939860) to simplify the syntax of string-concatenation *safely*.
- You can assign individual columns of the `NEW` row directly from the dynamic query.
- Use `GET DIAGNOSTICS _ct = ROW_COUNT;` to check if rows were found. [Per documentation:](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-DIAGNOSTICS)

  > Note in particular that `EXECUTE` changes the output of `GET DIAGNOSTICS`, but does not change `FOUND`.

Aside: the logic of the dynamic query is only correct for `BEFORE` trigger. An `AFTER` triggers would also see the newly inserted row.

Comment: Thanks @Erwin Brandstetter, so it can be applied, could you please tell me why you use `SELECT  floor(t.timeidx) + 1` in my script I only added it if ... `IF FOUND THEN` where is it in your example?, `_ct` means ROW COUNT? why the `_`"underscore" before it?, `FROM   %s t` means from table? %s means string? In `WHERE  t.fnname = $1` what does `$1` mean? what Im supposed to add after `, t.fnname  -- + 1 ??
            -- more?` sorry do you have any link tutorial about that syntax you used?, I just can't recognize my script logic, in the script you provide, thanks for your support.

Comment: *1.* If the `SELECT` finds no row, nothing is assigned, so I simplified to a *single* step where your original first assigns a variable and then assigns `NEW.timeidx`. *2.* I removed the "more .." parts now - was trying to address the unclear part, assuming you want to assign more than one columns. *3.* Read the manual or find [related answer here](http://dba.stackexchange.com/search?q=[plpgsql]+EXECUTE+NEW) or [on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[plpgsql]+[dynamic-sql]+EXECUTE+NEW+trigger)