# Trigger function using current row and current table name as variables (final part)

Tags: postgresql, trigger, postgresql-9.1, plpgsql, dynamic-sql

Like [detailed in my first question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/112184/postgresql-trigger-function-that-selects-from-current-table) I have a **Postgres 9.1** database with multiple tables that have the exact same column names, they only vary in their column values:

```
tbl_log_a
tbl_log_b
tbl_log_c
...
```

26 tables (from a to z). Each table has a trigger that calls a trigger function named `trfn_tbl_log_%letter%` (from `a` to `z`) which does the exact same thing:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION trfn_tbl_log_a_timetypespan()
  RETURNS trigger AS
$BODY$
DECLARE
v_timetype character varying;
v_timestmp_timetype timestamp without time zone;
v_timetypespan_resume interval;
v_stmtserial real;
v_sumtimetypespan_fnname interval;

BEGIN

IF NEW.timetype = 'lap' THEN
  SELECT timetype, timestmp, timetypespan FROM tbl_log_a WHERE fnname = NEW.fnname AND (timetype = 'start' OR timetype = 'resume') ORDER BY stmtserial DESC LIMIT 1 INTO v_timetype, v_timestmp_timetype, v_timetypespan_resume;
    IF v_timetype = 'start' THEN
      NEW.timetypespan := age(NEW.timestmp, v_timestmp_timetype);
    ELSIF v_timetype = 'resume' THEN
      SELECT timestmp FROM tbl_log_a WHERE fnname = NEW.fnname AND timetype = 'start' ORDER BY stmtserial DESC LIMIT 1 INTO v_timestmp_timetype;
      NEW.timetypespan := age(NEW.timestmp, v_timestmp_timetype) - v_timetypespan_resume;
    ELSE
      RAISE EXCEPTION USING MESSAGE = 'There is not any previous row...';
    END IF;

ELSIF NEW.timetype = 'resume' THEN
  SELECT timestmp FROM tbl_log_a WHERE fnname = NEW.fnname AND (timetype = 'start' OR timetype = 'lap') ORDER BY stmtserial DESC LIMIT 1 INTO v_timestmp_timetype;
    IF FOUND THEN
      NEW.timetypespan := age(NEW.timestmp, v_timestmp_timetype);
    ELSE
      RAISE EXCEPTION USING MESSAGE = 'There is not any previous row...';
    END IF;

ELSIF NEW.timetype = 'total' THEN
  SELECT stmtserial FROM tbl_log_a WHERE fnname = NEW.fnname AND timetype = 'total' ORDER BY stmtserial DESC LIMIT 1 INTO v_stmtserial;
  SELECT SUM(timetypespan) FROM (SELECT DISTINCT ON (floor(timeidx)::int) floor(timeidx)::int timeidx, timetypespan
  FROM tbl_log_a WHERE fnname = NEW.fnname AND timetype = 'lap' AND stmtserial > coalesce(v_stmtserial, 0) ORDER BY 1, 2 DESC) a INTO v_sumtimetypespan_fnname;
    IF v_sumtimetypespan_fnname NOTNULL THEN
      NEW.timetypespan := v_sumtimetypespan_fnname;
    ELSE
      RAISE EXCEPTION USING MESSAGE = 'There is not any previous row...';
    END IF;

END IF;
return NEW;

END
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE;
```

Trigger definition:

```
CREATE TRIGGER trfn_tbl_log_a_timetypespan
  BEFORE INSERT ON tbl_log_a
  FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE trfn_tbl_log_a_timetypespan();
```

So I have to create 26 trigger functions, one for each `tbl_log_%letter%`. I am trying to replace all of them with a single, generic trigger function.

We worked out a solution with dynamic SQL [under my previous question with a simplified function](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/112288/trigger-function-using-current-row-and-current-table-name-as-variables/112297). Can the same technique be extended to this more complex scenario?

```
EXECUTE format($$...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this should work (untested):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION trfn_tbl_log_timetypespan()  -- generic name
  RETURNS trigger AS
$func$
DECLARE
   _timetype varchar;
   _timetypespan_resume interval;
   _ct int;
BEGIN

CASE NEW.timetype
WHEN 'lap' THEN
   EXECUTE format($$
      SELECT timetype, timetypespan, age($1, timestmp)
      FROM   %s
      WHERE  fnname = $2
      AND    timetype IN ('start', 'resume')
      ORDER  BY stmtserial DESC
      LIMIT  1$$
    , TG_RELID::regclass)
   USING NEW.timestmp, NEW.fnname
   INTO  _timetype, _timetypespan_resume, NEW.timetypespan;

   CASE _timetype
   WHEN 'start' THEN  -- do nothing

   WHEN 'resume' THEN
      EXECUTE format($$
         SELECT age($1, timestmp) - _timetypespan_resume
         FROM   %s
         WHERE  fnname = $2
         AND    timetype = 'start'
         ORDER  BY stmtserial DESC
         LIMIT  1$$
       , TG_RELID::regclass)
      USING NEW.timestmp, NEW.fnname
      INTO  NEW.timetypespan;

   ELSE
      RAISE EXCEPTION 'There is no previous row.';
   END CASE;

WHEN 'resume' THEN
   EXECUTE format($$
      SELECT age($1, timestmp)
      FROM   %s
      WHERE  fnname = $2
      AND    timetype IN ('start', 'lap')
      ORDER  BY stmtserial DESC LIMIT 1$$
    , TG_RELID::regclass)
   USING NEW.timestmp, NEW.fnname
   INTO  NEW.timetypespan;

   GET DIAGNOSTICS _ct = ROW_COUNT;

   IF _ct > 0 THEN  -- do nothing
   ELSE
      RAISE EXCEPTION 'There is no previous row.';
   END IF;

WHEN 'total' THEN
   EXECUTE format($$
      SELECT COALESCE(SUM(timetypespan), $1)
      FROM (
         SELECT floor(timeidx)::int, max(timetypespan) AS timetypespan
         FROM   %1$s
         WHERE  fnname = $2
         AND    timetype = 'lap'
         AND    stmtserial > coalesce(
                 (SELECT stmtserial
                  FROM   %1$s
                  WHERE  fnname = $2
                  AND    timetype = 'total'
                  ORDER  BY stmtserial DESC
                  LIMIT  1), 0)
         GROUP  BY 1
         ) sub$$
    , TG_RELID::regclass)
   USING NEW.timetypespan, NEW.fnname
   INTO  NEW.timetypespan;

   GET DIAGNOSTICS _ct = ROW_COUNT;

   IF _ct > 0 THEN  -- do nothing
   ELSE
      RAISE EXCEPTION 'There is no previous row.';
   END IF;
END CASE;

RETURN NEW;

END
$func$  LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

This is a follow-up to my previous answer to your previous question. Find explanation there:

- [Trigger function using current row and current table name as variables](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/112288/trigger-function-using-current-row-and-current-table-name-as-variables/112297#112297)

While being at it, I simplified a couple of things. Like: the second `SELECT` in your first `ELSIF` branch was just a repetition of the `SELECT` one level above. I merged that for no cost.

I also removed a couple of unnecessary intermediary steps and assigned to fields of `NEW` directly where applicable. That's why I could remove most of your variables.

Aside: If `timeidx` only has positive numbers you can use the cheaper `trunc(timeidx)` instead of `floor(timeidx)`.

#### To understand the dynamic part more easily ...

If you would implement the same just for `tbl_log_a` - i.e., the effectively executed code for `tbl_log_a` (after applying `format()` and `EXECUTE`) looks like this:

```
...

CASE NEW.timetype
WHEN 'lap' THEN
   SELECT timetype, timetypespan, age(NEW.timestmp, timestmp)
   FROM   tbl_log_a
   WHERE  fnname = NEW.fnname
   AND    timetype IN ('start', 'resume')
   ORDER  BY stmtserial DESC
   LIMIT  1
   INTO  _timetype, _timetypespan_resume, NEW.timetypespan;

   CASE _timetype
   WHEN 'start' THEN  -- do nothing

   WHEN 'resume' THEN
      SELECT age(NEW.timestmp, timestmp) - _timetypespan_resume
      FROM   tbl_log_a
      WHERE  fnname = NEW.fnname
      AND    timetype = 'start'
      ORDER  BY stmtserial DESC
      LIMIT  1
      INTO  NEW.timetypespan;

...
```

Comment: Thanks @Erwin Brandstetter, I wil test it, thanks again.

Comment: Thanks @Erwin Brandstetter. I have one doubt though, is there some performance lost by using this "dynamically determined table name" method compared to the set method (SELECT * FROM tbl_name)? thanks advanced.

Comment: Hi @Erwin Brandstetter, I have tried replacing floor(timeidx) with trunc(timeidx) in the Trigger Function, but then it shows me an error "near trunc" when running it. I have tried also truncate? am I doing something wrogn? Thanks Advanced.

Comment: @Natysiu16: Performance depends on many factors. Details: http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/8189/3684. You should be able to replace [`floor()` with `trunc()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-math.html).  What's the data type of `timeidx`?

Comment: Hi @Erwin Brandstetter, the datatype of `timeidx` is `real`. Also I have tried to see why the second `SELECT` in  my first `ELSIF` branch was a repetition of the `SELECT` one level above, you mean this right? `SELECT timetypespan FROM tbl_log_a WHERE fnname = NEW.fnname AND timetype = 'resume' ORDER BY stmtserial DESC LIMIT 1 INTO v_timetypespan_resume;` is selecting `timetypespan`, the one level above line is selecting `timetype` both are different columns, do you meaned that?. Thanks Advanced.

Comment: @Natysiu16: **1.** `trunc()` should just work and is  a bit faster. It's really not important, it was just an aside. See fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/9eecb7db59d16c80417c72d1e1f4fbf1/2893. **2.** Yes, different columns, but *same row*. I select both columns at once which costs almost nothing, while executing another query is expensive.

Comment: sorry, completed forgot to check it xD

Comment: but @Erwin Brandstetter, it the first `SELECT` it selects `WHERE (timetype = 'start' OR timetype = 'resume')` and in the second `SELECT`(the first ELSIF statement) it selects `WHERE timetype = resume` are they the same row? do you mean those two, right? You mean I could add `timetypespan` to the first `SELECT` to replace the second `SELECT` am I right? Could you please very briefly tell me how would you shrink that part of my script without using the "dynamically determined table name" just using the proper table names Thanks Advanced.

Comment: *Same* row. `CASE _timetype ... WHEN 'resume' THEN` means that, in this case, the first row according to your sort actually has `timetype = 'resume'`, you don't have to run the query another time. Test it, it should do the same, just faster. You have to test it anyway, you can't just implement a solution from a friendly stranger on the internet. I added yet more explanation.

Comment: Thanks @Erwin Brandstetter for pointing out my duplicated `SELECT`. I replaced it in the first `SELECT`, tested and it worked very well, though I still had to create a variable to store the `timetypespan`. (shown in the question). I saw that there are some pros and cons regarded to performance when using this dynamically set tablename method. Given the current escenario which one would you suggest? The dynamically set tablename method or having one Trigger Function for each different table name? (I have joined all my 2 Trigger Functions in only one now) Thanks Advanced.

Comment: Dynamic SQL or 26 functions with static SQL? Hard to say. If you `INSERT` *many* rows in the same session, static SQL may prove a bit faster, because query plans are reused like with prepared statements. The dynamic variant is more complex, you need someone to understand plpgsql properly. If that is no problem and `INSERT` performance is either not critical or you do not insert many rows in the same session, the dynamic variant is more elegant and may even be faster. *One* function instead of 26 has a couple of general benefits.

Comment: Thanks @Erwin Brandstetter I run this trigger function every two seconds, for each %letter% tablename, so in two seconds I run it 26 times, I insert only one row each time the Trigger Function is run. I guess that's what you mean by "many rows in the same session". Thanks for your support and help me improve my script, very ilustrative indeed. Thanks.

Comment: @Natysiu16: The use case where static SQL can win is if the *same* trigger function is called many times in the *same session*. One or two rows for each table is *not* such a use case. Only if you insert repeatedly *in the same session*, then prepared statements for *static* SQL can be reused. I suggest to run tests with your actual environment.