# Column name as an argument of the function called in the trigger (PostgreSQL)

Tags: postgresql, trigger, functions, plpgsql, parameter

I looked at all similar questions, but it seems I didn't have enough knowledge to apply them to my issue.

Take a look at the following code. The bottom line is that I have a function that updates the `updated_at` field, the field is updated for the table for which the trigger was fired.

```sql
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE types(
    id SMALLINT GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY,
    type TEXT UNIQUE,
    updated_at TIMESTAMPTZ
);


CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION update_column()
RETURNS TRIGGER AS $$
BEGIN
    NEW.updated_at = now();
    RETURN NEW;
END;
$$ language 'plpgsql';


CREATE TRIGGER column_was_updated BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE OF type
ON types FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE
update_column();


INSERT INTO types (type)
VALUES ('type1'), ('type2');


SELECT * FROM types
```

I want to do the following: when calling the function from the trigger, pass a column name as an argument to the function to replace the literal column name `updated_at`, something like this:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION update_column()
RETURNS TRIGGER AS $$
BEGIN
    NEW.column_name = now();
    RETURN NEW;
END;
$$ language 'plpgsql';


CREATE TRIGGER column_was_updated BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE OF type
ON types FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE
update_column('column_name');
```

How can I achieve this?

P.S. I use PostgreSQL v.14.

Comment: The keyword to search is "dynamic SQL".

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Trigger function using current row and current table name as variables (final part)](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/112324/trigger-function-using-current-row-and-current-table-name-as-variables-final-pa)

Comment: @mustaccio can you suggest a code that suits my situation? As I said in the question - I looked at all similar questions, but it seems I didn't have enough knowledge to apply them to my issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You *can* do that. It's simple, too:

```
-- trigger function
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION update_column()
  RETURNS trigger
  LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$func$
BEGIN
   NEW := json_populate_record(NEW, json_build_object(TG_ARGV[0], now()));
   RETURN NEW;
END
$func$;

-- trigger
CREATE TRIGGER column_was_updated
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE OF type ON types
FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE FUNCTION update_column('updated_at');
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=3bed57ae956a1976d33eba6ef10ee2ad)*

Use the [special variable `TG_ARGV`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-trigger.html) for trigger functions, and [`json_populate_record()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSON-CREATION-TABLE) to set a field dynamically. See:

- [How to set value of composite variable field using dynamic SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7782641/939860)

Doesn't mean you *should*, though. Typically, you either just use a [column `DEFAULT`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-default.html):

```
CREATE TABLE types (
  id smallint GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY
, type text UNIQUE
, updated_at timestamptz DEFAULT now()  -- here!
);
```

That can be overwritten with input, though, so it's weaker than a trigger overwriting any input.

Or you write a separate function for every trigger. Like the one you already have. Simple enough. Means a separate trigger function for every involved table, but execution is faster without the dynamic element.

There is precious little space between those simple options for the "smart" solution above.