# Can't execute dynamic DDL, argument is NULL

Tags: postgresql, partitioning, plpgsql, dynamic-sql

I'm running PostgreSQL 9.4.4.
I'm new to Postgres (used to Oracle & SQL Server) so I might be doing something really silly.

I'm trying to dynamically create partitions for a table. I've got the individual parts of the code working however I can't get the function to execute the dynamic DDL statements. If I replace the execute with an insert into a log table, the statements that are generated are valid and I can run them myself but if the function attempts to execute the following error is produced:

```
select part_test();
ERROR:  query string argument of EXECUTE is null
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function phil_test() line 18 at EXECUTE statement
```

A reproducible function is as follows:

```
create table harry(logged_time timestamp, id integer);

create or replace function part_test () returns void as $$
declare
rec record;
begin
for REC in SELECT 'create table if not exists '||'harry'||'_'
                ||to_char(date_trunc('day', my_date), 'YYYY_MON_DD')
                ||' (check (logged_time>=DATE'''
                ||to_char(date_trunc('day', my_date), 'YYYY_MON_DD')
                ||''' and logged_time < DATE'''
                ||lead(to_char(date_trunc('day', my_date), 'YYYY_MON_DD'),1)
                  over (order by date_trunc('day', my_date))
                ||''')) inherits ('||'harry'||');' STMT
                FROM generate_series
                        ( '2015-SEP-01'::timestamp 
                        , '2015-SEP-10'::timestamp
                        , '1 day'::interval) my_date
LOOP
    execute REC.STMT;
END LOOP;
end;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Comment: If any operand is `null` then `||`  will yield `null` as well. So, one of your arguments is `null`.

Comment: Your problem is that `lead()` returns a NULL as the 10th value in the series and that renders the whole text NULL.  This can be easily found out if you  systematically do what @a_horse_with_no_name suggests above.  This also means that you have only 9 statements logged and a NULL instead of the last one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[@dezso already explained](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/115644/cant-execute-dynamic-ddl-argument-is-null#comment209977_115644) the direct cause of your error. But the whole function is needlessly convoluted. Use instead:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION part_test()
  RETURNS void AS
$func$
DECLARE
   _sql text;
BEGIN
   FOR _sql IN
      SELECT format ('
         CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS harry_%s (
           CHECK (logged_time >= date %L AND logged_time < date %L)
         ) INHERITS (harry)'
       , to_char(d, 'YYYY_MON_DD')  -- safe against SQL injection!
       , d::date, d::date + 1)
      FROM  generate_series (timestamp '2015-09-01'
                           , timestamp '2015-09-09'  -- 1 day before last
                           , interval  '1 day') d
   LOOP
   -- RAISE NOTICE '%', _sql;  -- to debug
      EXECUTE _sql;
   END LOOP;
END
$func$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

#### Major points

- Use [`format()`](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/49718/3684) to make concatenating statements simpler and safer.
- No need for [`date_trunc()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-TRUNC), the result of `to_char()` is the same.
- You don't need a `record` variable, it's just `text`.
- You don't need a window function, just add 1 day to the start.
- *Always* use [ISO 8601 format](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/datatype-datetime.html#DATATYPE-DATETIME-DATE-TABLE) for date and timestamp literals. Those work irregardless of your current locale settings.
  I am using default format in the `CHECK` constraint now. (`date` parameters to `format()` are cast to `text` with default format automatically.) You might consider the pattern `'YYYY_MM_DD'` instead of <strike>`'YYYY_MON_DD'`</strike> for the table name as well.
- Resulting table names are lower case (like they should be), because I did not double-quote.

  - [Are PostgreSQL column names case-sensitive?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20880247/939860)
- Not sure why you compare `logged_time` to a `date`, and not a `timestamp` or `timestamptz`. There may be a problem with time zones / volatility lurking there. [Consider `timestamptz`.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9576170/939860) Or if the column is actually a `date` type, don't call it "time" ...

The formatted date happens to be safe against SQL injection. Else you have to do more. Consider:

- [SQL injection in Postgres functions vs prepared queries](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/49699/sql-injection-in-postgres-functions-vs-prepared-queries/49718#49718)

Comment: Did you mean `YYYY-MM-DD`, or the version with the underscores?

Comment: Thank you. ☺A lot of the nasty-ness was just to get something reproducible and rip it out of a larger procedure.

Comment: @dezso: Yes, thanks. I fixed my bug in the date format in the CHECK constraint and simplified a bit more.