# Union tables by mask in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, functions, dynamic-sql, union

In database I have many tables like with names:

```
"t_2015_09_01_z15"
"t_2015_09_02_z15"
"t_2015_09_03_z15"
"t_2015_09_04_z15"
"t_2015_09_05_z15"
...
"t_2015_10_01_z15"
"t_2015_10_02_z15"
"t_2015_10_03_z15"
"t_2015_10_04_z15"
"t_2015_10_05_z15"
...
```

Please help create function which union tables by mask, for example

```
SELECT maskunion('public', 'mask', 'tablename');
```

where public - scheme name, mask - mask name ('t_2015_09_' - union all tables for 09 mounth, 't_2015_' - union all tables for 2015 year), tablename - output table name.

I found a similar function https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4202135/how-to-drop-multiple-tables-in-postgresql-using-a-wildcard footgun, but this function is for deleting tables by mask. Now I manually union each table by query:

```
CREATE TABLE t_2015_10 AS
SELECT * FROM t_2015_10_10_z15
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM t_2015_10_11_z15
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM t_2015_10_12_z15
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM t_2015_10_13_z15
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM t_2015_10_14_z15
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM t_2015_10_15_z15;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a safer and more elegant version of your function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION maskunion(_schema text, _tblbase text, _target text)
  RETURNS void AS
$func$
DECLARE
   _safe_target text := quote_ident(_schema) || '.' || quote_ident(_target);
BEGIN
   -- EXECUTE 'DROP TABLE IF EXISTS ' || _safe_target;  -- possibly dangerous!
   -- safer alternative:
   IF to_regclass(_safe_target::cstring) IS NOT NULL THEN
      RAISE EXCEPTION 'Target already exists: >>%<<', _safe_target;
   END IF;

   EXECUTE (
      SELECT 'CREATE TABLE ' || _safe_target || ' AS TABLE '
          || string_agg(quote_ident(schemaname) || '.'
                     || quote_ident(tablename), ' UNION ALL TABLE ')
      FROM   pg_tables
      WHERE  schemaname = _schema
      AND    tablename LIKE (_tblbase || '%')
      ORDER  BY tablename  -- better retain order
   );
END
$func$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

This assumes the same schema for target and source tables.
Same call as in your own answer:

```
SELECT maskunion('public', 'tiles_2015_10_', 'newtable');
```

This concatenates and executes a command of the form:

```
CREATE TABLE newtable AS
          TABLE t_2015_10_10_z15
UNION ALL TABLE t_2015_10_11_z15
UNION ALL TABLE t_2015_10_12_z15
...
```

#### Major points

- Like [@Craig commented](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/118718/union-tables-by-mask-in-postgresql#comment216681_118734): [`CREATE TABLE AS`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-createtableas.html) is much more elegant.
- I added a check whether the target table exists. Blindly dropping any table passed as parameter would make the function quite dangerous.
- [`TABLE tbl` is just short for `SELECT * FROM tbl`.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30275979/is-there-a-shortcut-for-select-from-in-psql/30276023#30276023)
- [How to check if a table exists in a given schema](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24089729/939860)
- Make sure to escape identifiers properly:

  - [SQL injection in Postgres functions vs prepared queries](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/49699/sql-injection-in-postgres-functions-vs-prepared-queries/49718#49718)

BTW, the [footgun function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4202280/939860) you refer to is a bit dated. You can `TRUNCATE` or `DROP` multiple tables with one command, and current Postgres has more elegant options for dynamic SQL:

- [Truncating all tables in a Postgres database](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12082038/939860)

Answer (score 3):

Based on [footgun](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4202135/how-to-drop-multiple-tables-in-postgresql-using-a-wildcard) function I write next function

```
DROP FUNCTION maskunion(text,text,text);
--
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION maskunion(IN _schema TEXT, IN _parttionbase TEXT, TEXT) 
RETURNS void 
LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS
$$
DECLARE
    row     record;
BEGIN
    EXECUTE 'DROP TABLE IF EXISTS ' || $3;
    EXECUTE 'CREATE TABLE ' || $3 || '
        (
          ogc_fid integer,
          wkb_geometry geometry(Geometry,4326),
          date character varying,
          x character varying,
          y character varying,
          z character varying,
          count character varying
        )';

    FOR row IN 
        SELECT
            table_schema,
            table_name
        FROM
            information_schema.tables
        WHERE
            table_type = 'BASE TABLE'
        AND
            table_schema = _schema
        AND
            table_name ILIKE (_parttionbase || '%')
    LOOP
        EXECUTE 'INSERT INTO ' || $3 || ' SELECT * FROM ' || quote_ident(row.table_name);
    END LOOP;
END;
$$;

SELECT maskunion('public', 'tiles_2015_10_', 'newtable');
```

But there I used pre-created structure of new table. It will be possible I try change this query. If there is another solution, please write answers.

Comment: Good on you for making an effort at it. For the definition you can use `CREATE TABLE ... LIKE ...` rather than repeating the columns, assuming there's another table with the same structure like a partition parent. If you want to empty the table, use `TRUNCATE TABLE` rather than `DROP` and `CREATE`.