# Query count(*) using except is different from using left join

Tags: postgresql

I have the following setup:

1. First, I create a temp table `q10c_debug_sql` to avoid clutter

```
create table q10c_debug_sql as
SELECT 
      movie_id, 
      company_id, 
      company_type_id 
    FROM 
      "postgres"."imdb_int"."movie_companies" 
    WHERE 
      (company_id) IN (
        SELECT 
          company_id 
        FROM 
          "postgres"."imdb"."q10c_company_name"
      ) 
      AND (company_type_id) NOT IN (
        SELECT 
          company_type_id 
        FROM 
          "postgres"."imdb_int"."company_type"
      )
```

The resulting table is an empty table

```
postgres=# select * from q10c_debug_sql;
 movie_id | company_id | company_type_id 
----------+------------+-----------------
(0 rows)
```

2. Now, I issue the following two queries

```
postgres=# select count(*) from (select * from imdb_int.movie_companies except select * from q10c_debug_sql) as foo;
  count  
---------
 2549109
(1 row)

postgres=# select count(*) from (select * from imdb_int.movie_companies as a left join q10c_debug_sql as b on a.movie_id = b.movie_id and a.company_id = b.company_id and a.company_type_id = b.company_type_id) as foo;
  count  
---------
 2609129
(1 row)
```

As one can see they return different count. On paper, these two queries are equivalent and should return `2609129`, the size of `movie_companies` table:

```
postgres=# select count(*) from imdb_int.movie_companies;
  count  
---------
 2609129
(1 row)
```

I don't know why this happens? I want to use EXCEPT for clarity but the query gives unexpected result. Any pointers are appreciated.

My psql versions

```
psql (15.3 (Ubuntu 15.3-1.pgdg20.04+1), server 13.11 (Ubuntu 13.11-1.pgdg20.04+1))
```

Answer (score 1):

It turns out `EXCEPT` returns only distinct values, i.e., EXCEPT returns any distinct values from the left query that are not also found on the right query. Thus, semantically, `EXCEPT` is not the same as left join: the former is set semantics but the latter is bag semantics.

Thanks to [this page](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/forums/topic/left-join-vs-except) for pointer.

```
postgres=# select count(distinct(movie_id, company_id, company_type_id)) from imdb_int.movie_companies;
  count  
---------
 2549109
(1 row)
```

Comment: EXCEPT is synonym for EXCEPT DISTINCT. There Is also EXCEPT ALL. In the same way the other set operators have two variants, UNION, UNION ALL, INTERSECT and INTERSECT ALL

Comment: @Lennart-SlavaUkraini Thanks for the informative comment.

Comment: FWIW, there are some surprising effects using <SETOP> DISTINCT on bags. One example is that A UNION A may have less cardinality than A. Then throw null into the mix and we are in for a treat;-)

Comment: About `EXCEPT ALL`: https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/120680/3684, https://stackoverflow.com/a/19364694/939860