# Passing ROWTYPE parameter to EXECUTE

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql, dynamic-sql, postgresql-8.3

I am developing a function in Postgres which aims to recover for each record of a query the value of a result of a check contained in a set of functions. Only one of these functions will return the correct value. These functions have a common prefix 'fn_condition_' and receive an object of type 'my_table' as parameter.

As the number of functions that make the check is unknown, I decided to consult the Postgres catalog, from the table `pg_catalog.pg_proc` searching for functions with the prefix 'fn_condition_' and dynamically execute them with [`EXECUTE`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/interactive/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-EXECUTING-DYN).

My problem is the correct form to pass the parameter for `EXECUTE`.

```
create or replace function test_conditions()
returns void as 
$$
declare
    v_record my_table%rowtype;
    v_function pg_proc%rowtype;    
begin 
    set search_path = 'pg_catalog';

    for v_record in (select * from my_table where id in (1,2,3)) loop
        for v_function in (
            SELECT  p.proname
            FROM    pg_namespace n
            JOIN    pg_proc p
            ON      p.pronamespace = n.oid
            WHERE   n.nspname = 'operacional'
            and p.proname like ('fn_condition\\_%')
            order by p.proname) 
        loop
         -- execute 'select ' || v_function.proname || '(' || v_record || ')';  -- ???
        end loop;
    end loop;
end;
$$ 
language plpgsql;
```

How to pass `v_record` properly in the commented `EXECUTE` command in the function above?

```
execute 'select ' || v_function.proname || '(' || v_record || ')';  -- ???
```

**Example function:**

```
create or replace function fn_condition_1(p_record my_table)
returns bigint as 
$$
begin 
    if ($1.atributo1 > $1.atributo2) then
        return 1;
    end if;
    return null;
end;
$$ 
language plpgsql;
```

Comment: `set search_path = 'pg_catalog';`  in the function body is almost certainly wrong (in multiple ways). What is the schema of `my_table`?

Comment: I know this does not answer the question, but please consider upgrading your DB - it is currently 7 versions behind.

Comment: The whole idea behind this approach is .. dubious. You are wide open to SQL injection. The procedure seems very inefficient. There is probably a better approach.

Comment: The schema of table `my_table` is public. This example is only ilustration of my real problem. My single problem in this scope is to pass the rowtype object for a function `fn_condition_1`. @ErwinBrandstetter

Comment: And you are serious about Postgres 8.3? It's not a typo and you mean 9.3 by any chance?

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter, it's not a typo. I'm working in a legacy project and I don't have liberty for upgrade the database.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the [`USING` clause of `EXECUTE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-EXECUTING-DYN) to pass values safely and efficiently. That's not available in your outdated version 8.3, yet. There it could could work like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION test_conditions()
  RETURNS SETOF bigint
  LANGUAGE plpgsql
  SET search_path = 'public' AS
$func$
DECLARE
   _rec    record;
   _func   text;
   _result bigint;
BEGIN
   FOR _func in
      SELECT  p.proname
      FROM    pg_catalog.pg_namespace n
      JOIN    pg_catalog.pg_proc      p ON p.pronamespace = n.oid
      WHERE   n.nspname = 'operacional'
      AND     p.proname LIKE E'fn\\_condition\\_%'  -- no parens, proper string
      ORDER   BY p.proname  -- no parens
   LOOP
      FOR _rec in
         SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE id IN (1,2,3)  -- no parens needed
      LOOP
         EXECUTE 'SELECT ' || quote_ident(_func) || '(' || quote_literal(_rec) || ')'
         INTO _result;
         RETURN NEXT _result;
      END LOOP;
   END LOOP;
END
$func$;
```

Call:

```
SELECT * FROM test_conditions();
```

If you use `set search_path = 'pg_catalog';` in the function body, then your table in the `public` schema is not visible any more. And it would be a very bad idea to globally `SET` the search path. The effect stays for the duration of the session. You could use `SET LOCAL` to contain it to the transaction, but that would still be a bad idea. Instead, if you really need to, set the environment of the function only, like demonstrated.
More about the search path in Postgres:

- [How does the search_path influence identifier resolution and the “current schema”](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9067777/939860)

Just executing a `SELECT` without assigning or returning the result would be pointless. Use the `INTO` clause of `EXECUTE` and then `RETURN NEXT`. In modern Postgres you would replace the inner loop with `RETURN QUERY EXECUTE`.

Use `quote_ident()` and `quote_literal()` to escape identifiers and literals properly when building a dynamic query string. In modern Postgres you would use `format()`.

It's not very efficient to cast the whole row to it's string representation, escape and cast back. This alternative approach has to read from the table repeatedly, but is cleaner otherwise (the row is passed as value directly):

```
  FOR i IN
     VALUES (1), (2), (3)
  LOOP
     EXECUTE 'SELECT ' || quote_ident(_func) || '(t) FROM my_table t WHERE id = ' || i
     INTO _result;
     RETURN NEXT _result;
  END LOOP;
```

#### Example function

You can also radically simplify your example function with this SQL function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION fn_condition_1(p_record my_table)
  RETURNS bigint
  LANGUAGE sql AS
$func$
   SELECT CASE WHEN $1.atributo1 > $1.atributo2 THEN bigint '1' END
$func$;
```

Comment: Erwin, thank you for your answer. It worked perfectly. Moreover I learned other things. Thank you again.

Comment: thanks,  i had similar problem because of these types record and rowtype, and your answer fix my problem (version 9.6)