# Sort output of plpgsql function

Tags: postgresql, order-by, postgresql-9.6, dynamic-sql, plpgsql

I'm creating a function in Postgres 9.6 that compares two schemas with the same tables. I want to find tables which are empty in one schema but populated in the other. I'm avoiding the `reltuples` attribute found in the information schema because it is not guaranteed to be correct.

So far I have this function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.compare_schemas_by_table_emptiness(schema1 text, schema2 text) 
RETURNS TABLE(tablename text, schema1_ct integer, schema2_ct integer, match boolean) AS $$
DECLARE
    schema1_tables CURSOR FOR
        select pg_tables.tablename
        from pg_tables
        where schemaname ~ schema1
        order by tablename;
        schema1_ct int;
        schema2_ct int;
BEGIN
    FOR table_record IN schema1_tables LOOP
        EXECUTE 'SELECT count(*) FROM ' || schema1 || '.' || table_record.tablename INTO schema1_ct
        EXECUTE 'SELECT count(*) FROM ' || schema2 || '.' || table_record.tablename INTO schema2_ct
        RETURN QUERY EXECUTE 'SELECT ''' || table_record.tablename || '''::text,' || schema1_ct || ',' || schema2_ct || ',' (schema1_ct >= 0) = (schema2_ct >= 0)
END LOOP
END; $$ LANGUAGE pgpgsql
```

But I'm really only interested in the cases where the output's `match` column is `false`, that is, one table is empty and one table is not empty. How I can I sort my output so that row where `match = false` are shown first?

Comment: *How I can I sort my output so that row where match = False are shown first?* `order by match, ...`

Comment: Typos like `pgpgsql` and missing `;` indicate that's hand-knit dummy code. Please show what you actually tested. And have you considered running `ANALYZE` on involved tables? Then you can work with `pg_class.reltuples` ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While returning rows from a loop directly, the sort order is determined by the loop. PL/pgSQL builds up the result set and you can still raise an exception to prevent the function from returning anything until the last moment. (There is a [code example in the manual.](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-RETURNING)) But there is no way to re-order the result set before finally returning. You would have to add `ORDER BY` to the *function call* for that:

```
SELECT * FROM public.compare_schemas_by_table_emptiness('foo', 'bar')
ORDER  BY match;
```

`FALSE` sorts before `TRUE`, so non-matches come first.

> But I'm really only interested in the cases where the output's `match` column is `false`.

So don't do more work than required. This function does what you need, efficient and **safe against SQL injection** (unlike your original):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.compare_schemas_by_table_emptiness(_schema1 text, _schema2 text) 
  RETURNS TABLE(tablename text, schema1_ct bigint, schema2_ct bigint)
  LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$func$
BEGIN
   FOR tablename IN
      SELECT quote_ident(t.tablename)  -- must be table-qualified, due to dupe in OUT parameters!
      FROM   pg_catalog.pg_tables t
      WHERE  t.schemaname = _schema1
      ORDER  BY 1
   LOOP
      EXECUTE format(
         'SELECT (SELECT count(*) FROM %1$I.%3$s)
               , (SELECT count(*) FROM %2$I.%3$s)
          WHERE  EXISTS (SELECT FROM %1$I.%3$s)
              <> EXISTS (SELECT FROM %2$I.%3$s)'
       , _schema1, _schema2, tablename)
      INTO schema1_ct, schema2_ct;

      CONTINUE WHEN schema1_ct IS NULL; -- happens when both or none have values
      RETURN NEXT;
   END LOOP;
END
$func$;
```

Call:

```
SELECT * FROM public.compare_schemas_by_table_emptiness('foo', 'bar');
```

Counting can be expensive with big tables, so this function only counts when required.

Identifiers may or may not require double-quoting and have to be treated like user input to be safe. See:

- [SQL injection in Postgres functions vs prepared queries](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/49699/sql-injection-in-postgres-functions-vs-prepared-queries/49718#49718)