# How to use user defined exception - PostgreSQL Function

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql, error-handling, exception

Can you please provide syntax for to use user defined exception in PostgreSQL function?

Suppose I want to handle below user defined exception.

```
SQL Error [22023]: ERROR: password is too short.
```

There are multiple SQLSTATE error code but not able to find what is the SQLSTATE code for this error. I used above which is 22023 but not resolved.

We have below code we are able to manage unique violation related exception but not able to manage for "password is too short". could you help me with the syntax?

Code:

```
begin
EXECUTE 'ALTER USER ' || $1 || ' WITH PASSWORD '''|| $2||'''' ;
        EXCEPTION WHEN "Password is too short" 
        THEN RAISE DETAIL 'Please check your password';
        
INSERT INTO pwdhistory (usename,password,changed_on) values($1,md5($2),now());
        EXCEPTION WHEN unique_violation 
        THEN RAISE DETAIL 'Password already used earlier. Please try again with another password.';

end;
```

Comment: Maybe you  might consider providing a bit more code - i.e. the calling function &c.?

Comment: @Vérace, Please check my updated Question

Comment: You show `$1` and `$2`, but not the function header declaring those parameters. Please always include the function header. `CREATE FUNCTION ...` And your version of Postgres, obviously. Finally, I have read the question a couple of times, and it's still not clear to me what the question is, ***exactly***. Please clarify.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Trapping and raising errors

To **trap errors**, use only *one* `EXCEPTION` clause in PL/pgSQL code. It can have multiple `WHEN` clauses. (But you seem to need only *one*. See below.)

You can work with error codes as with condition names. The list of [error codes can be found in the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/errcodes-appendix.html).

Also consider the Postgres [manual page on **Trapping Errors** in PL/pgSQL](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-ERROR-TRAPPING):

> The condition names can be any of those shown in [Appendix A](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/errcodes-appendix.html). A
> category name matches any error within its category. [...] Also, an
> error condition can be specified by `SQLSTATE` code; for example these
> are equivalent:
>
> ```
> WHEN division_by_zero THEN ...
> WHEN SQLSTATE '22012' THEN ...
> ```

So you can trap errors and (re-)raise them with different or additional details.

**Raising your own errors** is a different matter.
Just use [**`RAISE`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-errors-and-messages.html) with all desired details. Not need to *trap* an error first.

#### SQL injection

Unrelated to your core question, your displayed code is wide open to SQL injection.

> ```
> EXECUTE 'ALTER USER ' || $1 || ' WITH PASSWORD '''|| $2||'''' ;
> ```

**Do not use this.**

Would be fun to call your function with:

```
SELECT my_func('user1', 'pw1234567''; DELETE FROM pwdhistory; --');
```

(Or worse.) Boom. See:

- https://xkcd.com/327/

Handle user input properly. See:

- [SQL injection in Postgres functions vs prepared queries](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/49699/sql-injection-in-postgres-functions-vs-prepared-queries/49718#49718)

#### Function

Your function might look like this (assuming current Postgres 13):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION myfunc(_usename text, _password text)
  RETURNS void
  LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$func$
DECLARE
   _min_password_length int := 8;  -- specify min length here
BEGIN
   IF length(_password) >= _min_password_length THEN
      EXECUTE format('ALTER USER %I WITH PASSWORD %L', _usename, _password);
   ELSE  -- also catches NULL
      -- raise custom error
      RAISE EXCEPTION 'Password too short!'
      USING ERRCODE = '22023'  -- 22023 = "invalid_parameter_value'
          , DETAIL = 'Please check your password.'
          , HINT = 'Password must be at least ' || _min_password_length || ' characters.';
   END IF;

   
   INSERT INTO pwdhistory
          (usename, password, changed_on)
   VALUES ($1     , md5($2) , now());

EXCEPTION
   -- trap existing error and re-raise with added detail
   WHEN unique_violation THEN  -- = error code 23505   
      RAISE unique_violation
      USING DETAIL = 'Password already used earlier. Please try again with a different password.';
END
$func$;
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=909742199d8bbdc924bacbff3c2d3adf)*

Note the use of `format()` to properly quote name and value, and defend against SQL injection.

Call:

```
SELECT myfunc('usr', 'pw'); -- PW obviously too short ...
```

Produces:

> ```
> ERROR:  Password too short!
> DETAIL:  Please check your password.
> HINT:  Password must be at least 8 characters.
> CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function pg_temp_5.foo(text,text) line 8 at RAISE
> SQL state: 22023
> ```

```
SELECT myfunc('usr', 'repeated_pw');
```

Produces:

> ```
> ERROR:  unique_violation
> DETAIL:  Password already used earlier. Please try again with a different password.
> CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function pg_temp_5.foo(text,text) line 21 at RAISE
> SQL state: 23505
> ```