# Evaluate comparison operator from table column

Tags: postgresql, dynamic-sql, plpgsql

Is it possible to expand a field value into a comparison operator?   Something like this:

```
create table math (
    value1 int,
    value2 int,
    operator text
);
insert into math values(1,2,'>=');

select * from math where value1 operator value2;
```

PS: I know that it is possible to solve this use case by means of `case when`, but want to know if there is an alternative solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Yes**, possible. You need dynamic SQL to evaluate the expression.

#### Unsafe

A simple, naive approach. A bit simpler and faster than the safe approach.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION eval_unsafe(_operand1 int, _operand2 int, _operator text, OUT _result bool)
  LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$func$
BEGIN
   EXECUTE format('SELECT $1 %s $2', _operator)
   USING _operand1, _operand2
   INTO  _result;
END
$func$;
```

This is open to **SQL injection**. If your table source is safe, it's good enough. Is a table source *ever* safe, though?

#### Safe

I suggest this safe approach instead:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION eval_safe(_operand1 int, _operand2 int, _operator text, OUT _result bool)
  LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$func$
BEGIN
   EXECUTE format('SELECT $1 OPERATOR (%s) $2', (_operator || '(integer, integer)')::regoperator::regoper)
   USING _operand1, _operand2
   INTO  _result;
END
$func$;
```

Call for your example:

```
SELECT *
FROM   math m
WHERE  eval_safe(m.value1, m.value2, m.operator);
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=6d0f57b97dc476a27c108c9eca196f5c)*

The cast to the [object identifier type `pg_operator`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-oid.html#DATATYPE-OID-TABLE) enforces a valid operator (effectively checks against valid entries in the system catalog [`pg_operator`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/catalog-pg-operator.html)). The next cast to `pg_oper` is just a convenient way to get valid format for the [`OPERATOR` construct](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-PRECEDENCE).

See:

- [SQL injection in Postgres functions vs prepared queries](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/49699/sql-injection-in-postgres-functions-vs-prepared-queries/49718#49718)